# Shemona Asar Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred eighteen?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

218 years elapsed between the two renovations of the first Beis Hamikdash - the first one in the 23rd year of Yehoash's reign (II Kings 12:7), the second in the 18th year of Yoshiyahu's reign (II Kings 23:3). The respective years since Creation are 3084 and 3302.

([Seder Olam Rabbah, ch. 24](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34250&pgnum=89))

Answer (score 4):

218 men went to Israel with *Ovadya ben Y'chiel*. Source: [*Ezra* 8:9](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%97_%D7%98).

Answer (score 3):

The name Yehoshua is mentioned 218 times in Tanach.